# Closed button missing when open video

Tags: html, css

[image]

Here html code :

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="g-fullheight--xs g-bg-position--center swiper-slide" style="background: url('img/1920x1080/02.jpg');">
                    <div class="container g-text-center--xs g-ver-center--xs">
                        <div class="g-margin-b-30--xs">
                            <h1 class="g-font-size-35--xs g-font-size-45--sm g-font-size-55--md g-color--white">More Experience<br>That Inspires Us</h1>
                            <a class="js__popup__video" href="video popup/123.mp4" title="Intro Video">
                            <i class="s-icon s-icon--lg s-icon--white-bg g-radius--circle ti-control-play"></i>
                        </a>
                            <div data-aos="fade-up">                        
                    </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and CSS code :

```
/* Video v2 */
.s-video-v2__bg {
  position: absolute;
}

.s-video-v2__bg:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(34, 35, 36, 0.85);
  content: " ";
}
```

I've tried some code but still can't bring up [x] button on pop up video
Thanks a lot for help.

Regards,
Avaron

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the file specified in the `<a>` href tag is the video you are opening.
Href will redirect to the URL specified within the tag. You can see this in the address bar.

The `<video>` tag is probably what you are after if you are wanting to have the video inside of the page without redirecting.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: I use pop-up video in one page. which is displayed in the given code for the video without the pop up. but thanks for helping